# How could I configure and properly create a WiFi hotspot in a big corporate lan?

Tags: networking, proxy, sharing, hot-spot, wireless-access-point

I've went through some tutorials regarding how to build a hotspot under Ubuntu. My Ubuntu is connected in a big corporate lan and will post settings later.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

My Wireless nic doesn not support hotspot creation, and my first question is **how could I know if an specific wireless usb card supports it**?

Second, once with the right wireless usb nic, I'll create the hotspot, but then, **which settings or show should I configure it so this Wireless connection can be used by others and make everything pass through my PC**?

Settings:

[image: network settings]

*PS: Everything on My PC -LAN- must go through proxy. It is already configured in network settings, but I also have to specify **10.2.0.4:6588** as proxy in Firefox, Chrome, and anything that wants Internet.*

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `iw list`?

Comment: @Wilf here is the output http://pastebin.com/cD22Xn6S

Answer (score 1):

1. if your wireless card supports Station (aka "infrastructure" ) mode or Access point mode (STA and AP respectively) it can be used to create a hotspot.
   For more information, have a look at [kernel.org's excellent documentation](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/modes)
   The easiest command to show what you've *currently* got is `sudo iw list | grep --after-context=5 "interface mode"`
2. The settings you are showing are on the network level in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) whereas the settings you need are on the datalink level (you need to read up and dig deeper then the stuff you already know, so I would advise you to actually buy 3 books:  W. Richard Stevens: TCP/IP Illustrated Volumes 1-3. (you know, the ones made from paper from trees)  ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Fabby but how could I know if the external usb wireless nic supports STA and AP before purchasing it? Is there a list of nics that support it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's even hard to get a HCL for Linux and no HCL goes into the detail that you need.  The only way of getting the information you need, is googling and then contacting the manufacturer's website for the detailed specs. (or worse: emailing them)